# param is missing or the value is empty: user rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am getting the following error, when i try to submit my registration form.
param is missing or the value is empty: user

```
def user_params
   params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
end
```

Below is the request:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"YX0+4AeWlGWJiQZgbhV9cxi6TUCoibZfwh95BrK9iCQ=",
 "name"=>"asasa",
 "email"=>"asasas@asas.com",
 "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "confirm_password"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "commit"=>"Register"}
```

Below is my view

```
<%= form_tag users_path, class: "form-horizontal", id: "signupform" do %>

<%= end %>
```

Comment: If the key can't be found, there are several options: With no other arguments, it will raise an `ActionController::ParameterMissing` error; if more arguments are given, then that will be returned; if a block is given, then that will be run and its result returned. [`params.fetch(:user,{})'](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-fetch)

Comment: Maybe your problem is on controller method. Make shure you haven´t made a mistake between 'edit' and 'update' method.

Answer (score 23):

there is no `params[:user]` there, that's what the error is telling you.    Are you perhaps expecting your params to look like this?

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"YX0+4AeWlGWJiQZgbhV9cxi6TUCoibZfwh95BrK9iCQ=",
 "user" => {"name"=>"asasa",
            "email"=>"asasas@asas.com",
            "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
            "confirm_password"=>"[FILTERED]"
 },"commit"=>"Register"}
```

(i've added some indentation to highlight the structure).

If so, then you need to amend the form that submitted these params.  Either use  `form_for @user`, which will automatically set the input tags' `name` attributes to `user[name]`, `user[email]` etc, or manually set the field's names yourself, to `user[name]` etc.

Comment: Should i do something like this. <%= text_field_tag user[:name], nil, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Full Name" %>

Comment: @theJava May be you should use `form_for` like this `<%= form_for @user ,url: users_path do |f| %>` to get the Max's answer work.

Comment: Pavan the problem is my model is not extending ActiveRecord class. in that case how would i add user[name]

Comment: @theJava Then use the second option like this `<%= text_field_tag user[name], nil, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Full Name" %>`

Comment: I get this error pavan, undefined local variable or method `user' for #<#<Class:0x00000005dab1f0>:0x00000003430af0>

Comment: I think @Pavan meant `text_field_tag "user[name]"`

Comment: @MaxWilliams Yup!It was mistake.