# param is missing or the value is empty: holiday

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Hi guys new to ruby on rails, having this problem when i try to create new holiday records for a particular profile . it says error:

> param is missing or the value is empty: holiday.

```
# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def holiday_params
  params.require(:holiday).permit(:details, :Profile_id)
end
```

end

profile params:

private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_profile
      @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
    end

```
# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def profile_params
  params.require(:profile).permit(:firstname, :lastname, :work_email, :phone, :employment_type, :employment_start_date, :linkedin_profile, :nationality, :date_of_birth, :notes)
end
```

end

Comment: please show me your params (p params), you need to have {holiday: {details: 'some_data'}}

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that `params[:holiday]` exists for whatever path you are calling for the Holiday controller.

See: [param is missing or the value is empty: user rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24243253/param-is-missing-or-the-value-is-empty-user-rails-4)