# param is missing or the value is empty:user error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my sign up form i am getting following error:

**param is missing or the value is empty: user**

Controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @user = User.new(user_params)

  end

  def create 
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
        redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Signed up!"
    else
        render "new"
    end
  end


  private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email,:password)
  end
end
```

View:

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :email %><br/>
        <%= f.text_field :email %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :password %><br/>
        <%= f.password_field :password %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :password_conformation %><br/>
        <%= f.password_field :password_conformation %>
    </p>

<p class="button"><%= f.submit %></p>

<%end%>
```

already tried suggestions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24243253/param-is-missing-or-the-value-is-empty-user-rails-4) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24681280/param-is-missing-or-the-value-is-empty).
removing user_params call is creating **ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError** error in create method.

Comment: The view code belongs to which page? `new.html.erb`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have `params[:user]` in the `new` action, hence the error.

Rewrite `new` like this:

```
def new
  @user = User.new
end
```

And as @Pavan suggested, you should also make changes in `create` methods as well:

```
def create 
   @user = User.new(user_params)
   ...
end
```

here you change `params[:user]` to `user_params`.

Comment: And also `@user = User.new(params[:user])` should be `@user = User.new(user_params)` in `create` method.